# Show/hide div problems in IE7 only

Tags: javascript, css, html, toggle

I wondered whether someone might be able to help? I've tried and tried to find a solution myself, but nothing seems to work.

I have a horizontal list and when the user clicks on one of these links, a hidden div appears just below the list, filling the width of the overall container (950px).

This works absolutely perfectly on Firefox, Safari and IE8 but doesn't seem to work on IE7 (and possibly less, I haven't been able to check).

In IE7, the div causes the list to break, plonking the final list item on an extra line and (as a result, I presume?) pushing the div further down the page, so it's not flush with the bottom of the list. In fact, it appears just beneath the div with ID "highlightsbar".

Here is the relevant code - I'd be eternally grateful for any suggestions anyone might have!

**You can see this problem 'in action' at http://www.totalbackpacker.co.uk. (Interestingly, if I do a quick test with only the relevant bits of code at http://www.martinjefferies.co.uk/test.html, the problem isn't there. I'm not sure if that helps or not?!)**

Thanks,

Martin

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="navbar">

<ul>
<li class="left"><a href="#" title="Home"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/navbar/home.png" alt="Home" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Explore by country" onClick="toggle('submenu')"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/navbar/explorebycountry.png" alt="Explore by country" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Search"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/navbar/search.png" alt="Search" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Contact"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/navbar/contact.png" alt="Contact" /></a></li>
<li class="right"><a href="#" title="About"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/navbar/about.png" alt="About" /></a></li>

<div id="submenu" style="display: none; z-index:500;">
<div id="submenu-inner">

<?php
$categories = get_categories('child_of=7');
$count = 1; ?>
<div class="left">
Left hand links go here
</div>
<div class="right">
Right hand links go here
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<br /><a href="#" title="Close menu" onClick="toggle('submenu')">Close menu</a>
</div>
</div>

</ul>
<div class="clearer"></div>

<div id="highlightsbar">
<span class="title">Promotion:</span> Promotion info goes here.
</div><!--highlightsbar-->
</div><!--navbar-->

<div id="content">

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
margin:0 auto;
background:#E2E2E2;
width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
text-align:left;
width:950px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background:#FFFFFF;
padding:0 0 50px 0;
}

#header {
background:#be023a;
height:100px;
width:950px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#navbar {
background:#cc0000 url('http://www.totalbackpacker.co.uk/wp-content/themes/totalbackpacker/images/navbar.jpg') repeat-x;
height:70px;
width:950px;
}

#navbar ul {
float:left;
list-style:none;
margin:7px 0 0 10px;
padding:0;
height:40px;
}

#navbar li {
float:left;
}

#navbar li a {
display:block;
padding:3px 10px;
margin:0;
border-right:1px solid #ffffff;
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
line-height:15px;
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:normal;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
background:#cc0000;
}

#navbar img {
border:0;
}

#highlightsbar {
padding:0;
margin:3px 0 0 20px;
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:12px;
color:#666666;
text-decoration:none;
}

#highlightsbar .title {
text-transform:uppercase;
float:left;
font-weight:bold;
}

#highlightsbar .textwidget {
float:left;
padding:0;
margin:0 0 0 5px;
}

.clearer {
clear:both;
}

#submenu {
background:url('../images/submenushadow.png') left bottom repeat-x;
margin:30px 0 0 -10px;
padding:0 0 50px 0;
z-index:5000;
position:relative;
width:950px;
display:block;
}

#submenu-inner {
background:#ffffff;
border-left:5px solid #be023a;
border-bottom:5px solid #be023a;
border-right:5px solid #be023a;
padding:20px;
}

#submenu-inner .right {
float:left;
width:140px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#submenu-inner .left {
float:left;
width:140px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function toggle(id)
{
    el = document.getElementById(id);
    var display = el.style.display ? '' : 'none';
    el.style.display = display;
}
window.onload=function()
{document.getElementById('submenu').style.display='none';}

</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML structure is a bit odd, you are show/hiding `#submenu` when 'Explore by Country' is clicked, but it is inside the LI for 'About'.

I would also recommend that you use `position: absolute;` on `#submenu` if you want it to be removed from the document flow.

Comment: If you give your ul a width of 100%, it solves the problem of the last list item "About" pushing itself down to a second line.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan and @circusbred, although I double checked my code and `#submenu` doesn't seem to be in an `<li>`. I have updated the CSS to use `position:absolute;` but while that didn't have any effect in Firefox, it made things worse in IE7. Really appreciate your suggestions though guys. Can't understand why one of the links I included works and the other doesn't! It's driving me mad!

Comment: Cheers @Jawad. I gave that a go, and it prevents the last list item pushing itself down, as you suggested. I think it's now a case of figuring `position:absolute` - which works as it is in FF4 and IE8, just not in IE7. Grrr! ;)

Comment: Close your ul </ul>. In IE9 the div#submenu is a child of ul, while in IE7 it is the child of the last li

Comment: div#navbar{ position: relative;} - div#submenu{position: absolute; top: 15px; right: 1px;} - Works on IE7

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere @Jawad! I've closed the `<ul>` before `#submenu` is brought in, tweaked the CSS slightly and it's appearing where I want it to in both FF4, Safari and IE8. In IE7, it's way over to the right (outside the main container div, by the looks of it). It's at the correct level though ...

Comment: http://i55.tinypic.com/j7c0ft.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with.

Firstly, I created an extra div for the submenu - called `#submenu-outer`:

```
#submenu-outer {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
left:0;
display:block;
text-align:center;
margin:35px 0 0 0;
z-index:5000;
}
```

Then I made `#submenu` appear in the centre of the 100% outer div:

```
#submenu {
background:url('totalbackpacker.co.uk/wp-content/themes/totalbackpacker/images/…;) left bottom repeat-x;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0 0 50px 0;
width:950px; 
text-align:left;
}
```

Et voila! Thanks to everyone who helped along the way! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you pull it out and it works then it must be something in the surrounding code.

The most common issue with non javascript IE compatibility is IE will treat extra open tags and close tags differently than other browsers.

I suggest you look very closely at the html, or selectively add back HTML till you can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into using [conditional-includes](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for IE7 (forget about IE6 if at all possible). Here's a jsFiddle of the code I got working in my copy of IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/qjx4g/2/

What happened is that you shouldn't have your submenu code within your `#navbar` `<ul>` (i.e., close your `#navbar` (`</ul>`) and then put in your submenu's code) and whenever I have problems with a container with `position: relative` that contains content that is `float`ed, I change the container to use `position: absolute` and work from there (only in a conditional-include for IE7).

Comment: Thanks! I've finally cracked it!1. Created an extra div for the submenu - called `#submenu-outer`:

    #submenu-outer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin:35px 0 0 0;
    z-index:5000;
    }

2. Make `#submenu` appear in the centre of the 100% outer div:

    #submenu {
    background:url('http://www.totalbackpacker.co.uk/wp-content/themes/totalbackpacker/images/submenushadow.png') left bottom repeat-x;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0 0 50px 0;
    width:950px;
    text-align:left;
    }

Et voila!

Comment: @Martin - you should post that as the solution and / or update the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qjx4g/2/) and post the new link to it.

Comment: Cheers @stealthyninja. Apparently I have to wait to mark my solution as an answer, but will do (and I'll update the jsFiddle (really clever tool by the way!) too). Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

1 - If you give your ul a width of 100%, it solves the problem of the last list item "About" pushing itself down to a second line.

2 - Close your ul . In IE9 the div#submenu is a child of ul, while in IE7 it is the child of the last li

3 - div#navbar{ position: relative;} - div#submenu{position: absolute; top: 15px; right: 1px;} - Works on IE7

[pic](http://i55.tinypic.com/j7c0ft.jpg)